# "reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd" kernel log message

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, usb-drive, dmesg

When steadily reading data off a connected via USB3 HDD drive (`cat /dev/sdx > /dev/null`) in a VirtualBox VM (Host: Fedora 37, guest: doesn't matter) I see a constant stream of kernel messages repeating every 1000 seconds or so:

```
[30690.822917] usb 6-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd
[31750.830800] usb 6-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd
[32943.838334] usb 6-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd
[33228.839274] usb 6-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd
[33921.890985] usb 6-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd
[34333.894787] usb 6-1.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 1 using xhci_hcd
```

What do they indicate? Is data being lost? Is my USB3 4-port hub faulty? Not enough power for the HDD (the USB3 hub is passively powered)?